# Change default console position in CodeBlocks

Tags: gnome-terminal, default, console, code-blocks

It's so annoying to drag it over and over again. How to change default position of a console?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use command line options to launch the terminal window with desired settings.

In codeblocks :

- Go to **Settings > Environment > General Settings**.
- Change the "Terminal to launch console programs" option to :

> **gnome-terminal --geometry=WIDTHxHEIGHT+XOFF+YOFF -x**
>
> **+XOFF :** The left edge of the window is to be placed XOFF pixels in from the left edge of the screen
> **+YOFF :** The top edge of the window is to be YOFF pixels below  the  top edge  of  the  screen

**I** used the following to have the terminal almost centered on my screen :

```
gnome-terminal --geometry=80x20+300+240 -x
```

[image: Dialog in codeblocks and place to launch the terminal with desired settings]

[Source 1](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/gnome-terminal.1.html)
[source 2](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man7/X.7.html)