# Code::Blocks output window Position in Ubuntu

Tags: software-center, code-blocks

When I write my program and then compile & run it, my output window appears at the bottom right corner so I have to drag & drop it to the center so I can enter my data.

Is there any way to make the default output window position the center of the screen?

I am running with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and code blocks version 13.12 that I installed from Ubuntu Software Center

[image]

Comment: i face this problem before the only solution i found to change from xterm to terminal , check this answer if you want to do that http://stackoverflow.com/a/13914740/4376397

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave an answer [in this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/748500/change-default-console-position-in-codeblocks/773254#773254) (the only difference being the terminal you want to use).
But if you want to keep using **xterm**, use the following command instead :

In codeblocks :

- Go to Settings > Environment > General Settings.
- Change the "Terminal to launch console programs" option to :

> **xterm -T $TITLE -geometry WIDTHxHEIGHT+XOFF+YOFF -e**
>
> **WIDTH :** The width of the terminal window
>   **HEIGHT :** The height of the terminal window
>   **+XOFF :** The left edge of the window is to be placed  XOFF pixels in from the left edge of the screen
>   **+YOFF :** The top edge of the window is to be YOFF pixels below the top edge of the screen

**I** used the following to have the terminal almost centered on my screen (**change them to fit your screen resolution**):

```
xterm -T $TITLE -geometry 80x20+300+240 -e
```