# How can I view the C++ code result in terminal instead of xterm

Tags: command-line, 18.04, c++, programming, code-blocks

I have just started to learn C++
and I am using code block to do all the work of c++.
but when the code is run the result is displayed in something called XTERM.
I would be happy to know if there is any way by which I can see the result of my code in the Linux terminal itself.

code blocks version: 16.01
Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Comment: When running your C++ program, just compile it with `g++` and run it wil `./a.out`

Comment: See [How to change code::blocks default console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937840/how-to-change-codeblocks-default-console/23727622) and related [Change default console position in CodeBlocks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/748500/change-default-console-position-in-codeblocks)

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Settings -> Environment -> Terminal to Launch Console Programs".
Then select "gnome-terminal -x"